# How can we throw an expcetion with a message?

Tags: c++, exception

I need to throw an exception and print some helpful message. I tried this:

```
throw std::exception("message"); 
throw std::exception(std::string("message"));
```

untill I found that `std::exception` [had only two constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception):

```
exception();
exception( const exception& other );
```

So what is the good way?

Comment: You should use the derived types. For example, `throw std::runtime_error("message...")` or `throw std::invalid_argument("message...")`.

Comment: Part of the logic is that when the runtime is out of memory, it throws `std::bad_alloc` which is a `std::exception`. If `std::exception` needed memory to store that helpful message, creating a `std::bad_alloc` would be a real problem: you'd need memory to report you are out of memory (!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to throw it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed: ") + message);
throw std::runtime_error("Error: " + message);
```

Also you can use the [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/format/)

```
throw std::runtime_error(boost::format("There is an exception") % message);
```

Answer (score 1):

std::exception has an inbuilt virtual called .what() to retrieve things local to the exception in generic catch statements. It's for you to set it.

Otherwise except and catch specifically and consider logging from the catch, which in itself isn't bad practice, but of course if you use the same exception in several places far from ideal if you wanted a centralized message (it's best done that way if you want to log where you caught rather than what).

Wide catches, or worse catch all, have their risks, and as there is no way for a catch all to know the details of your specific exceptions what() is the only guaranteed commonality that I know of.